# Catel.Fody and validation

Tags: c#, catel

I'm usign Catel to create my WPF application. I'm also using Fody.Catel plugin to forget about these Catel-like dependency properties.

But right now I'm about to create validation for fields, and I cannot handle that.

From Catel example it should look like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
{
    validationResults.Add(FieldValidationResult.CreateError(FirstNameProperty, "First name is required"));
}
```

but I do not have `FirstNameProperty`, because I's done by Fody.Catel automatically.

How can I handle validation with Fody.Catel?

Answer (score 1):

Just provide the actual property name:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
{
    validationResults.Add(FieldValidationResult.CreateError("FirstName", "First name is required"));
}
```